# " RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called" when subclassing threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to run as many threads of class Observer as there are elements in list dirlist.
When I run it python console it works all right.

```
class Observer(Thread):
    def run(self):
        naptime = random.randint(1,10)
        print(self.name + ' starting, running for %ss.' % naptime)
        time.sleep(naptime)
        print(self.name + ' done')

observers = {}
for d in dirlist:
    observers[d] = Observer()
    observers[d].start()
```

But when I try to do it from a Master thread which is supposed to spawn the Observer threads I get errors.

```
class Master(Thread):
    def __init__(self, dirlist):
        self.dirlist = dirlist
    def run(self):
        observers = {}
        for d in dirlist:
            observers[d] = Observer()
            observers[d].start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(3600)

master_thread = Master(dirlist)
master_thread.start()
```

The call to `Master.start` results in:

> ```
> RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
> ```

This looks strange to me.
I am unable to understand whats the difference between both cases.
Can anybody figure out a solution to my problem ?

Somehow following doesn't produce an error, and I don't understand why.

```
class Master(Thread):
    def set(self, dirlist):
        self.dirlist = dirlist
    def run(self):
        observers = {}
        for d in dirlist:
            observers[d] = Observer()
            observers[d].start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(3600)

master_thread = Master()
master_thread.set(dirlist)
master_thread.start()
```

Comment: how about calling Thread.__init__ as the error said?

Comment: Should be `for d in self.dirlist:`. As it is, `for d in dirlist:` refers to a global. To be a proper [sample](http://sscce.org/), the code should be complete, which means it should provide a minimal implementation of `Observer`, and should be just code so it can be used directly (which means don't copy the python prompt & indentation from the interpreter). Edit your question to fix the sample. Lastly, which version of Python are you working with?

Answer (score 45):

```
>>> master_thread.start()
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
```

Make sure to call `Thread.__init__()` in your `Master.__init__`:

```
class Master(Thread):
    def __init__(self, dirlist):
        super(Master, self).__init__()
        self.dirlist = dirlist
```

Comment: @Nullpoet: "Still doesn't work" Isn't much of an error message.  Update your question to show the new code and the new error!

Comment: Worth noting that in Python3, the preferred way to call a method on the parent class is to use [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) without an argument, in order to make code more maintainable. So that line becomes just:
`super().__init__()`

Answer (score 16):

Well i know it's late to answer but, what the hell, i am a newbie in python but this same thing was happening to me, so i went back to read the python tutorial and it has some differences with what we both we're trying, hope it helps.
instead of this

```
import threading

class Master(Thread):
    def set(self, dirlist):
        self.dirlist = dirlist
    def run(self):
        observers = {}
        for d in dirlist:
            ...
```

class according to the python tutorial:

```
class Master(threading.Thread):
```

this line is missing:

```
threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

so it will end up being:

```
import threading

class Master(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dirlist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dirlist = dirlist
    def run(self):
        observers = {}
        for d in dirlist:
            ...
```

and that should work, at least work for me.
I hope it was helpfull.

And your second try using the set method works, because you are not overriding the

> `__init__` method

from Thread therefore the original init method from the parent class is used it runs as it's supposed.

Comment: The appropriate way to call base class method is through `super()`.

Comment: You need to indent the two method definitions because they're members of the Master class.

Answer (score 6):

Error is clear, you should call `thread.__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, dirlist):
    super(Master, self).__init__()
    self.dirlist = dirlist
```

Comment: The `super` call is incorrect. You're supposed to pass the subclass.

Comment: @Nullpoet, it should work with calling `Thread.__init__`. Make sure there isn't any other problem. And you can't use dirlist parameter without init.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super), you can use the simpler form `super().__init__()`.