# myThread issue, outdate issue?

Tags: python, multithreading

When i run a script, it executes except for the threading...I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 133, in <module>
    thread = myThread(i, "Thread " + str(i), i);    
  File "script.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.name = name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 971, in name
    assert self.__initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() not called
```

Is this because the myThread reference is outdated to the Python2.7/threading.py? Should the script lines be changed to something else?

Comment: does `myThread` call `super(...).__init__(...)` or `Thread.__init__(...)`? Because if it doesn't, it needs to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [" RuntimeError: thread.\_\_init\_\_() not called" when subclassing threading.Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445742/runtimeerror-thread-init-not-called-when-subclassing-threading-thread)

Comment: The specific line is: `threading.Thread.__init__(self)`

Comment: The full code sections are:

`class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        print "[+] Starting " + self.name
        connect(self.name, self.counter, eachThread, self.threadID)`

and

`while (i < int(threads + 1)):
 thread = myThread(i, "Thread " + str(i), i); 
 threaders.append(thread)
 i += 1
 thread.start()`

If anybody can see an anomaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "[+] Starting " + self.name
        connect(self.name, self.counter, eachThread, self.threadID)
```

This should fix this issue just misplaced this line "threading.Thread.**init**(self)"

Comment: Nice. Worked. Thanks!